# Do conditional mgfs relate to the joint mgf similarly to marginal mgfs?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, moment-generating-function

Given a (for example, bivariate) random vector, say $(X,Y)$, with joint distribution $f(x,y)$ and moment-generating function $$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2),$$

we can say that the moment-generating functions of the marginal distributions are
$$M_X(t) = M_{XY}(t,0) \text{ and } M_Y(t) = M_{XY}(0,t).$$

So, if we want to find the moment-generating function of $X$ conditional on $Y$, $M_{X\mid Y}(t)$, is there a similar relationship to the joint pdf, or does the conditional distribution $f_{X \mid Y}(X \mid Y = y)$ have to be calculated before this moment-generating function can be computed?

Comment: Since mgfs are defined as expectations, you could consider the law of total expectation. See e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/431667/7224).